# Getting occurrences of different values on nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-object

I've an array of objects like this:

```js
arrObj = [{
  id: 1
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
},{
  id: 1
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jane'
    }
  }
},{
  id: 1
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
}]
```

And I needs get a summary of occurrences for different values, like this:

```js
{ jane: 1, jhon: 2 }
```

The big problem is that I need pass the nested prop dynamically:

```js
getSummary('data.info.name',obj) //--> { jane: 1, jhon: 2 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, this is just hint. you need to do error handling if some input is not having correct nested keys.

```js
let arrObj = [{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
},{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jane'
    }
  }
},{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
}]

const getSummary = (dynamicKeys,obj) => {
  const list = dynamicKeys.split('.');
  const op = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let n = 1, key = obj[i][list[0]];
    while (list.length > n) {
      key = key[list[n]];
      n++;
    }
    op[key] = op[key] ? op[key] + 1 : 1;
  }
  return op;
}

const test = getSummary('data.info.name', arrObj);
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be as below. Here at first given prop is found out from each element of arrayObj. If the finding isn't successful, the element is skipped and move to next. When the finding is successful, append the finding value to summary if it does not exist in summary or increment the existing value. You can change the code as your requirements.

```js
const arrObj = [{
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
}, {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jane'
    }
  }
}, {
  id: 1,
  data: {
    info: {
      name: 'jhon'
    }
  }
}];


const getSummary = (prop, arr) => {
  const keys = prop.split('.');
  const findPropValue = (elem) =>
    keys.reduce((val, key, index) => {
      if (index === 0) return elem[key];
      return (val && val[key]) || val
    }, null);
  return arr.reduce((sum, curr) => {
    const key = findPropValue(curr);
    if (!key) return sum;
    sum[key] = (sum[key] && sum[key] + 1) || 1;
    return sum;
  }, {});
};


console.log(getSummary('data.info.name', arrObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Go over elements using `forEach`. For each object, access the value and build a `res` object with keys as value (eg jane) and object values are aggregated.
[Access the value, by `split` the path, access object nested using `reduce`)

```js
const getSummary = (path, items) => {
  const paths = path.split(".");
  const res = {};
  items.forEach((item) => {
    const value = paths.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[cur], item);
    res[value] = (res[value] ?? 0) + 1;
  });
  return res;
};

arrObj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      info: {
        name: "jhon",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      info: {
        name: "jane",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      info: {
        name: "jhon",
      },
    },
  },
];

const output = getSummary("data.info.name", arrObj);
console.log(output);
```